# MYSQL - select data between two dates

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

so i have this table

```
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+------------+
| ID_Client  | Code_House | Jangka_Kredit | Angsuran_Kredit | Date       |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+------------+
| PR-331     | HM-0023    | 5 Years       |        10500000 | 2010-11-20 |
| PR-331     | HM-0045    | 3 Years       |         4800000 | 2011-04-02 |
| PR-331     | HM-0050    | 3 Years       |         5200000 | 2011-05-03 |
| PR-332     | HM-0024    | 10 Years      |          800000 | 2010-06-08 |
| PR-333     | HM-0035    | 8 Years       |         2000000 | 2011-03-13 |
| PR-334     | HM-0036    | 5 Years       |         2900000 | 2012-08-03 |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+------------+
```

and want to select data between early 2010 and end of 2011.
I have tried many formats but none of them work

*actually i have some tables and select data from some fields between 2010 and 2012

-Update
i tried this for one table and it works

```
where date(Date) between '2010-01-01' and '2012-01-01' ;
```

now i have to call some specific fields from some tables between 2 dates,
heres what i tried

```
 select Pembeli.ID_Pembeli,Pembeli.Nama_Pembeli,Taip_Rumah.Type_Rumah,Info_Rumah.Taip_Rumah.Kategori_Rumah,Info_Rumah.Harga_Rumah,Transaksi.Jangka_Kredit
    -> from Transaksi,Pembeli,Info_Rumah,Taip_Rumah
    -> where Pembeli.ID_Pembeli=Transaksi.ID_Pembeli and Info_Rumah.Kode_Rumah=Transaksi.Kode_Rumah and Info_Rumah.Kategori_Rumah=Taip_Rumah.Kategori_Rumah
    -> where date(Date) between '2010-01-01' and '2012-01-01' ;
```

it doesnt work

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: please post the code that not working.

Comment: You don't need two `where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you can't have two WHERE clauses in the same sentence. You have to change the second WHERE clause by AND like this:

```
select Pembeli.ID_Pembeli,
       Pembeli.Nama_Pembeli,
       Taip_Rumah.Type_Rumah,
       Info_Rumah.Taip_Rumah.Kategori_Rumah,
       Info_Rumah.Harga_Rumah,T
       ransaksi.Jangka_Kredit
from Transaksi,Pembeli,Info_Rumah,Taip_Rumah
where Pembeli.ID_Pembeli=Transaksi.ID_Pembeli and 
      Info_Rumah.Kode_Rumah=Transaksi.Kode_Rumah and 
      Info_Rumah.Kategori_Rumah=Taip_Rumah.Kategori_Rumah
      AND date(Date) between '2010-01-01' and '2012-01-01' ;
```